# Can you eat more calories than the body can store?

Tags: human-biology, fat-metabolism

I believe I have read that if the body takes in too many certain nutrients/vitamins, the body simply excretes them.

How does this behave with calories? If I have a daily consumption of exactly 2,000 calories, would the body gain more weight if I took 6,000 calories in one day or if I took 2,500 calories over 8 days?

I know that excess calories can be stored by the body, but is there a point where the body can't keep up and excrete the rest?

Comment: you will run into the issue of eating more than the body can digest first.

Comment: Even if you only eat chocolate or something similar? For example, I have a bar of chocolate here that has ~550 calories per 100 grams. There would be 4,000 extra calories 'only' 700 grams of chocolate. But I think that there are also things that have much more than that.

Comment: After googling I found out that Macadamia Nuts has 718 calories per 100 grams. Thats even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @John already pointed out, efficiency of digestion can be assumed to decrease in case of extreme uptake of excessive calories. (diarrhea)

In terms of the [excretory system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excretory_system): Proteins are generally strongly retained by the kidneys, while glucose famously could leave the body through urine (diabetes) but should be taken up by your cells under normal circumstances. Fats, as carried by transporter proteins, should not be excreeted either. So I don't think you would excrete many calories.

Also I remember some papers stating, that short-term excessive caloric uptake is correlated with down-regulation of glucose transporters to your brain, while prolonged uptake of excessive calories (more than around 3-7 days) leads to changes in the brain-barriers permeability properties. It was observed that this change in permeability has long-term fatalistic effects: It will cause hippocampal damage and in turn further cause high caloric intake as a behavioral change due to reduced internal cues that depend on the hippocampus.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6381074/